# Service worker inside Web Workers

Tags: web-worker, service-worker

What would be the correct way to implement a webworker that can use a service worker to handle network calls. For example

- I have an index.html file with its own logic for rendering data
- Then this web worker is responsible for sending the data that needs to be
  rendered and triggering the render process
- The webworker will use
  the service worker for fetching and caching the network requests/json
  data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web worker and the service worker are effectively independent.

If you have a service worker controlling a specific page, then any HTTP requests that originate from that page or from a web worker used on that page will trigger a `fetch` event on that service worker. This applies to HTTP requests triggered by either `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest` from the web worker. The web worker doesn't need to "know" about the service worker in advance or anything.

Note that a service worker can send and respond to `message` events just like a web worker can, so you might be able to get away with eliminating the web worker entirely and moving all your logic to the service worker. But that depends on what exactly your web worker was doing, and what level of support you want for browsers that support web workers but don't (yet) support service workers.

Answer (score 1):

Service Workers have limited lifetime. The browser aggressively unloads Service Workers, that's why `event.waitUntil(promise)` exists in the handlers (that's just a request though, the browser can still kill it)

For canonical service worker uses this is okay, but if you want to have a long running parallel process,you need a (Web) Worker.